# How can I create a Tensor with elements set to 1 by specific integer and fill with 0 to fit the width size

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

for example.
I have a tensor like
`a = tf.constant([4,2,1,3])`.

if I want to create a tensor with size [4, 5]

A tensor I need will contain following elements..

```
[[1,1,1,1,0],

[1,1,0,0,0],

[1,0,0,0,0],

[1,1,1,0,0] ]
```

How can I create this tensor?

Comment: This could help - [`Fill mask efficiently based on start indices`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58595650/fill-mask-efficiently-based-on-start-indices).

Comment: Thanks Devakar, after I search on the tf documentation I found this function to solve my problem.. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sequence_mask

Answer (score 1):

You can first create ones tensor and then pad to the same length. At the end, stack all tensors together.

```py
a = tf.constant([4,2,1,3], dtype=tf.int32)

def pad_to_same(t):
    return tf.pad(tf.ones(t, dtype=tf.int32), [[0,5-t]], constant_values=0)

res = tf.stack([pad_to_same(t) for t in a])

# <tf.Tensor: id=35571, shape=(4, 5), dtype=float32, numpy=
# array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
#        [1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
#        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
#        [1., 1., 1., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)>
```

**Update**
If you want to avoid for-loop, you can use `tf.map_fn`,

```py
def pad_to_same(t):
    return tf.pad(tf.ones(t, dtype=tf.int32), [[0,5-t]], constant_values=0)

res = tf.map_fn(pad_to_same, a)
```